# Display current time (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: google-sheets

i've created the google spreadsheet and wanted to display the current time (HH:MM:SS). I wrote the script using the Tools -> Script Editor as follows

```
function Timer() {
 var d = new Date();
 // var timeStamp = d.getTime();  // Number of ms since Jan 1, 1970

  // OR:

 var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString(); // "12:35 PM", for instance
}
```

How do i run this script in each cell when i select an action. Lets say an example when i select Login Time from the dropdown list, it should show me the current time in the cell. 
Could someone help me out.

I'm not good at writing code. I copied this code from google...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a [menu added to your sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_or_forms) that is calling your function.

```
function Timer() {
 var d = new Date();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 var range = sheet.getActiveCell(); // gets the highlighted cell
 //var range = sheet.getRange("A1"); //gets the cell A1

 range.setValue(d);

}
```

I would set the time [formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?hl=en) up in the spreadsheet proper

for reference:[Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)